# Can I improve upon window redraw and if so how can I?

Tags: winapi, gcc, user-controls, c++14

Some years ago (2008) I wrote an online **Child Support Calculator** using PHP/Javascript/Ajax/css [Advanced Child Support Calculator - May help to explain what I am replicating](http://www.tandm.flnet.org/ACSCalcV3.0.html).

Some time after (2009 I think) I started writing an equivalent for Windows and am now revisiting this. The fundamentals of this version are working.

**However, I have an issue with the window noticeably flickering/changing when controls are dynamically added and the window is redrawn/rebuilt.**

> Note! This calculator is specific to Australia.

**In short I'm looking for a way, if possible, to only refresh/re-display/redraw the window after all components have been added.**

Basically, the windows controls need to be dynamically added/removed depending upon the scenario (number of adults and children involved).

Adding or removing a child or adult or performing the calculation, results in a complete rebuild of the window. That is, all existing controls are destroyed and then all valid controls are added (this could perhaps be minimised via complex logic).

The issue is that controls are removed but briefly reappear (in an ordered fashion) causing the display to flicker (for want of a better description).

The following screen shots demonstrate the complexity factor (such as a child has a drop down for each defined adult), but not the *flicckering*(sic).

Here's a screen shot of the **Initial display** (OK pretty ugly at present) :-

[image: Initial Display]

And then if an **Adult** is added (*note that the child now has an **extra dropdown** for Adult 3, the new adult*):-

[image: Adult Added]

And now, an **Adult** (as above) and a **Child**:-

[image: Adult and Child Added]

Coding wise, there is a `RebuildAll` function. This has two main stages. (1) The removal of the controls. (2) The rebuild (recreation) of the appropriate of the controls (`Create Window`, `SendMessage`'s and then `ShowWindow`)

At a minimum there are 61 controls. The number of controls is 
23 + ((#children * 12) - 2) + (#children * (#Adults * 8 )) + ((#adults * 10) -4). It's likely suffice to say that the number of controls increases rapidly/exponentially.

I suspect that it might be possible to postpone the `ShowWindow` untill after all of the builds have been done. Is the solution, as simple (theoretically) as this, assuming that this is feasible or is there another way that would circumvent the need to change all the code to remove the 'ShowWindow' and add a ShowWindow at the end of the builds?

***Note replacing the individual `ShowWindow`'s with one significantly reduced the "flicker" but didn't eliminate it.*** (as per **Update** below).

---

> As an endnote I'm pretty sure that something should be feasible as the
>   windows program I have to date is a very poor reflection of the speed
>   of the browser/javascript version, which basically does the same thing
>   on windows (albeit 64bit).

---

## Update

I went through and commented out the `ShowWindows` in all the `AddItem????` functions and added a `ShowWindows` to the function that calls all the functions. This has improved matters. However, the numerous `DestroyWindow` calls still causes flickering when removing all of the controls. So now I guess that I'm looking for something that can disable them apparently doing an equivalent of `ShowWindow`.

### Update 2

I have found `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0);` (TRUE to turn drawing back on). However, this appears to supress the `DestroyWindow` in that the display aspect of the control remains (the controls themselves don't appear to respond though).

Comment: Ooops. GCC "Duh, my brain hurts" :) Sorry. Changed.

Comment: Can't we just have a [mcve], alongside a short problem description? The issue you're facing doesn't warrant more than a paragraph of text, or two maybe.

Comment: Flicker-free in Windows is hard, mkay.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, perhaps flicker is the wrong term. It's that in the second or so that it takes you can see the controls progressively disappear (it was also with controls re-appearing, but the change to only have the 1 ShowWindow has erradicated that, as per the Update). So I'm hoping that there is an equivalent method to only display the changed window after all controls have been destroyed.

Comment: @IInspectable, I will attempt to produce one. I'm not sure that I can though . However, I believe that the solution is a methodology that I have been unable to find through numerous attempts. I did try to highlight what I believe to be the issue (i.e. the Single bolded sentence, which does need to be changed to from ....added to deleted/destroyed).

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, the `AddItemEditTXT` function has several problems. The call to `CreateWindowEx` mixes an extended window style (`WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`) with regular window styles. This will be interpreted as `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` (neither style makes sense for an Edit control). And your `SendMessage`-call uses an MBCS-encoded string (`std::string`). You either need to call `SendMessageA`, use a `TCHAR`-based string, or switch to `SendMessageW` and `std::wstring`. The latter is highly recommended for a number of reasons.

Comment: @IInspectable I've written an example that adds 600 controls (EditText's) based upon the original code. On button click it then destroys all 600 and then adds another 600 (text displayed is changed). Although not instantaneous it's pretty quick takes about1 second and not obviously wrong. I've offset the second set from the first as it could be some optical illusion with positioning. In short the example doesn't yet reflect the issue. It might be control types, perhaps some require a lot more work than others. It's late here now. So I'm going to get some sleep and will re-visit this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a process of elimination I have cured the flicker with a combination of `ShowWindow`'s and `WM_SETREDRAW`'s at pertinent points.

To briefly re-describe the issue. When adding a child or adult, or performing a calculation. The entire display is rebuilt. The rebuild basically consists of 2 phases. First, destroying the existing control windows and then adding the new/replacement set of window's controls.

The resolution was to :-

1. Issue a **`ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_SHOW);`** (for the main/containing
   window) after all the pre-existing windows control's had been
   destroyed.
2. Issue a **WM_SETREDRAW FALSE message** as per `SendMessage(hwnd,
   WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0);` before rebuilding the windows controls.
   **Without** any `ShowWindow`'s being used.
3. Build the windows controls via the various functions.
4. Finally, when all the windows controls have been built, issue a
   **`ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_SHOW);`** (for the main/containing window).

Rather than seeing the controls appear and then disappear, "*the flickering*". The window is blank for a while and then the controls are displayed all at once.

I'm still confused about what is actually going on though, due to:-

After some thought I decided to use a `MessageBox` after all the destroys. When the message was displayed the window was blank. However, when the button was clicked and processing resumed then, in situations when the number of controls was relatively high, controls would appear and then disappear in an orderly fashion, albeit it momentarily.

> My guess, is that creating a control in an area where an existing
>   control had been, was causing that previous control to momentarily
>   display.

Comment: You may also want to look into DeferWindowPos() and friends.